# Why does my form work for creating new objects but not updating existing ones?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, routes, submit, ruby-on-rails-5

I want to build a form that can both create and update my model.  I have this

```
    <%= form_for @vote, :url => votes_path, :remote => true do |f| %>
            <%= f.hidden_field :person_id, :value => @person.id %>
            <%= f.text_field :score %>
            <%= f.submit %>
            <%= submit_tag 'Skip', :name => 'skip', :type => 'button' %>
    <% end %>
```

and in my routes file, I have

```
resources :votes
```

but when the "@vote" object exists and has an ID, the above form fails to submit, giving the error

```
POST http://localhost:3000/votes 404 (Not Found)
```

Below is how my controller is setup, although I feel like its not even getting that far when attempting to submit ...

```
class Vote < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :person
  belongs_to :user


  def create
    puts "vote params; #{vote_params}"
    @vote = Vote.new(vote_params)

    ...
  private

    def vote_params
      params.require(:vote).permit(:score, :person_id)
    end
```

Comment: When you `POST` to `votes_path` (note plural `votes`), you hit the `create` action. If you want to hit the `update` action, you need to `PUT` or `PATCH` to `vote_path` (notice singular `vote`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to allow both create and update method on your model `vote`, you can just skip using url and form_for will autodetect the REST call.

```
<%= form_for @vote, :remote => true do |f| %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :person_id, :value => @person.id %>
  <%= f.text_field :score %>
  <%= f.submit %>
  <%= submit_tag 'Skip', :name => 'skip', :type => 'button' %>
<% end %>
```

Now to create the object `vote` you need to make a POST call, e.g.

```
POST http://localhost:3000/votes
```

and to update the object, you need to make PUT/PATCH call e.g.

```
PUT http://localhost:3000/votes/:id
```